# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create directory public/assets//node_modules/font-awesome/fonts'

Tags: zend-framework2, xampp, composer-php

What I've done :

- I am using XAMP and I've cloned the project from git.
- Composer is up to date with npm update
- I am using Zend framework
- PHP 5.6.23
- I am trying to run the project, I am getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Unable to create directory
>   public/assets//node_modules/font-awesome/fonts' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php:76
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php(69):
>   Assetic\AssetWriter::write('public/assets//...',
>   'OTTO\x00\n\x00\x80\x00\x03\x00 CFF...') #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module/src/AsseticBundle/Service.php(513):
>   Assetic\AssetWriter->writeAsset(Object(Assetic\Asset\FileAsset)) #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module/src/AsseticBundle/Service.php(494):
>   AsseticBundle\Service->write(Object(Assetic\Asset\FileAsset)) #3
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module/src/AsseticBundle/Service.php(433):
>   AsseticBundle\Service->writeAsset(Object(Assetic\Asset\FileAsset)) #4
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfile in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TMS2/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php
>   on line 76

Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: Can you improve the question by adding which php, framework versions and 3rd party libraries are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change the privileges of folder. It should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

the command to change the access

```
chmod 755 -r <dir>
```

Can set less public permissions